# What happened to my $_GET?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, get

I have an `ec2` server on amazon and an `index.php` file.

This file has the following code:

```
<?php

    var_dump($_GET);

?>
```

I'm passing this `GET` parameter:

```
?code=settings
```

On localhost (wamp), I get this:

```
array (size=1)
  'code' => string 'settings' (length=8)
```

On my server, I get this:

```
array(2) { ["page"]=> string(0) "" ["lang"]=> string(0) "" }
```

The above test is after isolating the problem to the very least code lines.
I have no idea what are this parameters on the live site and don't have a clue where to begin investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an .htaccess file?
if so check if your query is not being rewritten, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w*)(/([a-z]{2}))?$ /index.php?page=$1&lang=$2
```

to keep your original query, you need to add [QSA] (query string append) to the end of the rule, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w*)(/([a-z]{2}))?$ /index.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [QSA]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it! I used .htaccess file from another site of mine and it had this missing [QSA].